# Targeting a class element node inside react function of createElement() class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to grab the current node of a function inside a `React.createElement()` function.

```
return React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
                return ({
                    expand: false
                });
            },
            expandLaunch: function() {
               this.setState({
                   expand: true
               });
               // want to do something like 
               // $('.text').css('display','block');
            },
            render: function() {
                var titlebar = React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    {className: 'titlebar', onClick: this.expandLaunch},
                    'Launcher'
                );
                //........
                var text = React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    {className: 'text'},
                    textarea
                );
                return React.createElement(
                        'div',
                        {className: 'box-wrapper'},
                        titlebar,
                        text
                );
            }
        });
```

So with the `expandLaunch()` function I wanted to target the element so I can manipulate the css and other possible functionality. FYI I am not using JSX, just regular jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

```
return React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return ({
                expand: false
            });
        },
        expandLaunch: function() {
           this.setState({
               expand: true
           });
           $(this.refs.text).css('display','block');
        },
        render: function() {
            var titlebar = React.createElement(
                'div',
                {className: 'titlebar', onClick: this.expandLaunch},
                'Launcher'
            );
            //........
            var text = React.createElement(
                'div',
                {className: 'text', ref: 'text'},
                textarea
            );
            return React.createElement(
                    'div',
                    {className: 'box-wrapper'},
                    titlebar,
                    text
            );
        }
    });
```

I do urge you to use the tools React gives you to achieve this, via dynamic `className`s or inline styles, rather than using jquery, which in many ways should be considered orthogonal to React.